# date_create and date_diff having issues when I use format or date_format

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function that takes in the date for start and end date as a range of dates of looking up reports. I have two tables with different type for start date, but the issue is this lookup must be able to show results from these two tables even the two columns are different from each other. The other table, let's call it table 1, contains the start date in milliseconds; that's how it was set up before. The input for this takes the date of when the reports were uploaded and convert it into milliseconds. The other table, table 2, takes the dates in automatically converts the date into something like this 2019-02-05T11:51:20 format; all start date from table 2 are in this format. This is the format that gets uploaded into the DB. I was told that that's how the android device was doing it, or that's how the input for the start date was written. The end dates for both tables are in milliseconds. I don't know why the end date for table 2 is stored in this format. Looking up reports that are from table 1 is fine. The form gives me the expected results, but when I search for reports from table 2, I get error(s) like

Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

```
function dateDifference($date_1, $date_2, $differenceFormat = '%a') // %a
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
    //$datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format($differenceFormat) * 8.64e+7;
}
```

I have also tried this but same thing.

```
// function dateDifference2($date_1, $date_2, $differenceFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:I:s') //Y-m-d\TH:i:s
// {
//  $dateTime1 = date_create($differenceFormat, $date_1);
//  $dateTime2 = date_create($date_2);
//      $interval = date_diff($dateTime1, $dateTime2);
//      return $interval->format($differenceFormat) * 8.64e+7;
// }
```

Can somebody help me out here? Thank you! 
NOTE: I can't change the type of dates for this. That's how the two were set up or written. I have no control over that. I can only do things based on what's given to me or what I have. The first app was written by a different group, and so as the second.

Comment: The issue in your code is very clear as the warn and error shows.

Comment: @KrisRoofe Yes, and I have tried everything I could to fix it, but I think having two different types of dates is the problem. But I have no control over the types or format of these dates. The app uses different language, and I am on the other side where I can only do so much based on what I get from the other side

Comment: `$datetime1` is set to the result of `format()`, for some reason. Thus, it's set as a string. Instead of calling `date_create()->format` you need to call `date_create_from_format()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php).

Comment: @yivi I have tried that, that did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with this line:

```
$datetime1 = date_create($date_1)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
```

Firstly, [`date_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) expects a string, not a value in milliseconds. You can work around that by using [`date_timestamp_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) and dividing the value by 1000.

Secondly, you are making `$datetime1` a string, not a `DateTime` object by the call to [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). You need to remove the `->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s")`;

So overall, you should change that first line to this:

```
$datetime1 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_1/1000);
```

You need to do a similar thing for `$datetime2`. Note that since `$date_1` could be numeric or a date string you need to check for that and change the code appropriately e.g.

```
function dateDifference($date_1, $date_2, $differenceFormat = '%a') // %a
{
    if (is_numeric($date_1)) 
        $datetime1 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_1/1000);
    else
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($date_1);
    $datetime2 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_2/1000);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    return $interval->format($differenceFormat) * 8.64e+7;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/YPKSi)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got rid off the errors, but this is what I get startDate BETWEEN 0 AND 0 this is part of the query that I have. I tried searching between February 5 and March 5.

Comment: @azunyan can you give me sample values for `$date_1` and `$date_2` that show this problem?

Comment: Yes, of course. For start date, I search February 05 and for end date, I search for March 5. That's like the range for the search, I can be in any range. The start date in the table has 02-05T11:51:20. For the end date, this is what I have 1551791511000

Comment: @azunyan I missed the part about the end times being in milliseconds. You will need to also use `$datetime2 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_2/1000);` and where the start time is a string, just use `$datetime1 = date_create($date1);`

Comment: Using $datetime1 = date_create($date1); and $datetime2 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_2/1000); only give me data from table 1. It's somehow skipping dates that are from table 2. And if I use both $datetime1 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_1/1000); and $datetime2 = (new DateTime())->setTimeStamp($date_2/1000); I get  BETWEEN 0 AND 0

Comment: @azunyan See my edit. I think that covers what you need to do. I've also added a demo.

Comment: @azunyan no worries. I'm glad we got it sorted out.